# Kivy garden mapview deploying error with Buildozer

Tags: android, deployment, kivy, buildozer

I am using kivy.garden.mapview for my application. Everything works properly, but problems arise when I try to deploy the application to Android with Buildozer. I set "garden_requirements = mapview" in the .spec file, and I always get the same error message: "Command failed: garden install --app mapview". The command fails even when I execute it on its own. The command "buildozer android debug deploy run logcat" produces the following output:

```
albi@albi-VirtualBox:~/CUCINA$ buildozer android debug deploy run logcat
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.19.7 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /home/albi/.local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Run 'git config --get remote.origin.url'
# Cwd /home/albi/CUCINA/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android.git
# Run 'git branch -vv'
# Cwd /home/albi/CUCINA/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
* master 1b3b0e3f [origin/master] Merge pull request #2225 from kivy/release-2020.06.02
# Run '/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install -q --user \'appdirs\' \'colorama>=0.3.3\' \'jinja2\' \'six\' \'enum34; python_version<"3.4"\' \'sh>=1.10; sys_platform!="nt"\' \'pep517<0.7.0"\' \'toml\''
# Cwd None
# Apache ANT found at /home/albi/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /home/albi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk
# Recommended android's NDK version by p4a is: 19c
# Android NDK found at /home/albi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c
# Check application requirements
# Check garden requirements
# Remove directory and subdirectory /home/albi/CUCINA/.buildozer/libs
# Run 'bash -c "source venv/bin/activate && env"'
# Cwd /home/albi/CUCINA/.buildozer
SHELL=/bin/bash
SESSION_MANAGER=local/albi-VirtualBox:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1718,unix/albi-VirtualBox:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1718
QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
COLORTERM=truecolor
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg
XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome-
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
QT4_IM_MODULE=ibus
LC_ADDRESS=it_IT.UTF-8
GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu
LC_NAME=it_IT.UTF-8
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu
LC_MONETARY=it_IT.UTF-8
SSH_AGENT_PID=1649
ANDROIDAPI=27
GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
PWD=/home/albi/CUCINA/.buildozer
PACKAGES_PATH=/home/albi/.buildozer/android/packages
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=ubuntu
LOGNAME=albi
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
ANDROIDNDK=/home/albi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c
XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS=JS ERROR;JS LOG
WINDOWPATH=2
HOME=/home/albi
USERNAME=albi
IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
LC_PAPER=it_IT.UTF-8
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME
VIRTUAL_ENV=/home/albi/CUCINA/.buildozer/venv
VTE_VERSION=6001
GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN=/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/66ea9009_ef14_420d_ae9a_ff4590d07de8
INVOCATION_ID=5f9f2518374145c29f2f6ad18acfb7f8
MANAGERPID=1473
CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=ibus
GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT=stderr
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
LC_IDENTIFICATION=it_IT.UTF-8
TERM=xterm-256color
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
USER=albi
ANDROIDMINAPI=21
GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE=:1.140
DISPLAY=:0
SHLVL=1
LC_TELEPHONE=it_IT.UTF-8
QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
LC_MEASUREMENT=it_IT.UTF-8
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
PS1=(venv)
LC_TIME=it_IT.UTF-8
ANDROIDSDK=/home/albi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk
JOURNAL_STREAM=9:32116
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
PATH=/home/albi/CUCINA/.buildozer/venv/bin:/home/albi/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/albi/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
GDMSESSION=ubuntu
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
LC_NUMERIC=it_IT.UTF-8
OLDPWD=/home/albi
_=/usr/bin/env
# Run 'pip install Kivy-Garden==0.1.1'
# Cwd None
Requirement already satisfied: Kivy-Garden==0.1.1 in ./.buildozer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in ./.buildozer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Kivy-Garden==0.1.1) (2.23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in ./.buildozer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests->Kivy-Garden==0.1.1) (2020.4.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in ./.buildozer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests->Kivy-Garden==0.1.1) (2.9)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in ./.buildozer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests->Kivy-Garden==0.1.1) (1.25.9)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in ./.buildozer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests->Kivy-Garden==0.1.1) (3.0.4)
# Create directory /home/albi/CUCINA/.buildozer/libs
# Install garden package mapview in buildozer_dir
# Run 'garden install --app mapview'
# Cwd /home/albi/CUCINA/.buildozer
Downloading http://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.mapview/archive/master.zip ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/albi/CUCINA/.buildozer/venv/bin/garden", line 189, in <module>
    GardenTool().main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/albi/CUCINA/.buildozer/venv/bin/garden", line 71, in main
    options.func()
  File "/home/albi/CUCINA/.buildozer/venv/bin/garden", line 109, in cmd_install
    fd = self.download(opts.package)
  File "/home/albi/CUCINA/.buildozer/venv/bin/garden", line 170, in download
    data += buf
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
# Command failed: garden install --app mapview
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     PATH = '/home/albi/CUCINA/.buildozer/venv/bin:/home/albi/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/albi/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/albi/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/albi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/albi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
#     VIRTUAL_ENV = '/home/albi/CUCINA/.buildozer/venv'
#     CC = '/bin/false'
#     CXX = '/bin/false'
#
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
albi@albi-VirtualBox:~/CUCINA$
```

I have tried everything I found on Stack Overflow, but nothing worked. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problematic error stems from this piece of information here:
`Kivy-Garden==0.1.1`

I had the same issue, buildozer, for some weird reason installs `Kivy-Garden` version `0.1.1` which produces that error when you try to install *ANY* garden flower. `Kivy` version `1.11.1` now uses `Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4` which works without issues.
If you install `Kivy-Garden==0.1.1` and try to install a package, it crushes with that error. However, If you upgrade to `Kivy-Garden==0.1.4`. The problem is that `buildozer` will install `Kivy-Garden==0.1.1` no matter what you do. So I tried a lot of things from downgrading buildozer to manually activating the environment that `buildozer` creates and upgrading garden there but when you run the buildozer command again. Buildozer will simply overwrite your upgraded garden AND install the non-working `0.1.1`.

Finally I just gave up and did the one thing I COULD do at this moment. Simply fix buildozer myself:

1. Activate your environment(assuming you have one)
2. Go to where `buildozer` is installed. In my case this is: `/home/samuel/repo/mobile/venv/finager/lib/python3.7/site-packages/buildozer-1.2.0.dev0-py3.7.egg/buildozer/__init__.py`. You can find that out by checking the paths in your logs.
3. Now go to `Line 533` and change where it says `pip install Kivy-Garden==0.1.1` to `pip install Kivy-Garden==0.1.4`
   That's it, your problem should go away now.

I hope they fix this soon as this is a pretty simple thing to do. `Kivy` itself requires `Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4` which makes me wonder why `buildozer` would want `0.1.1` when it clearly doesn't work

Comment: I followed your guidelines, however when I run "buildozer android debug deploy run logcat", buildozer still tries to install Kivy-Garden==0.1.1 and I don't know why. I don't have an environment. Could this be the problem?

Comment: probably but it could also mean that you modified the wrong buildozer, are you sure you have one buildozer.. eg buildozer for python 2 and buildozer for python3

Comment: what do you see when you run: `which buildozer`.. is it the one you modified?

Comment: It finally worked! I initially modified the wrong one. `which buildozer` allowed me to identify the right one. In my case the path is: `/home/albi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer`. Thank you very much!

Comment: The issue: https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/1186